# How can I disable embedded ActiveMQ-broker in ServiceMix?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I have ServiceMix 4.5.3 and would like to completely disable the internal/embedded ActiveMQ broker.
What is the best/easiest way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and works:

- Remove **"activemq-broker"** from **featuresBoot** list in
  `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`
- Remove file `etc/activemq-broker.xml`
- Run `features:uninstall activemq-broker` in Karaf console

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minimal distribution which AFAIR does not come with AMQ out of the box.

Otherwise you can modify the configuration file in `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` and remove activemq

Comment: Hi Claus, minimal distribution is a bit too minimal for my requirements. I tried with the etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg but amq kept running. But thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit and had success with the following:

1. remove the activemq-broker.xml from the etc directory (or rename to something like amq.old)
2. features:uninstall activemq-broker in karaf console

Step 2. may not be required, not sure

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit the featuresBoot in etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg and remove the activemq features.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the ServiceMix version 7.0.1

If you will not need need to install it back, in the file `org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` I just removed the line in `featuresRepositories=` part:

```
mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.14.5/xml/features, \
```

And to be sure ActiveMQ is not installed after a ServiceMix reset (e.g. servicemix clean) I also removed the three lines in `featuresBoot=` part of the same file:

```
activemq-broker-noweb, \
activemq-blueprint, \
servicemix-messaging
```

It looks like `servicemix-messaging` also depends on embedded ActiveMQ otherwise my ServiceMix does not start.

For still being able to integrate with an external ActiveMQ instance, I added:

```
activemq-camel, \
```